# Using objects in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays

I have simple class:

```
public class Item {

private double price;
private String name; 

public double getPrice() {return Price;}

}
```

and I have some diffrent objects of Item in the basket:

```
ArrayList basket = new ArrayList();
basket.add(newItem);
```

I would like to use something like that to get price:

```
basket.get(0).getPrice()
basket.get(1).getPrice()
```

Of course it doesn't work.

Comment: Google for Java Generics and/or Type Casting.

Comment: `List<Item> basket = new ArrayList<Item>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics.

```
List<Item> basket = new ArrayList<Item>();
basket.add(new Item());
basket.get(0).getPrice();
```

Comment: This is not type casting - this is using generics so that you can avoid type casting.

Comment: Damnit what the hell am I doing? You're right. I apologise. I've now updated it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList basket = new ArrayList();
```

Two things wrong here:

- you are using [raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it); you should use [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) (<= click link for tutorial)
- the type of `basket` should not be the implementation type `ArrayList`, you should program against the interface `List`

It should look like this:

```
List<Item> basked = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I know, but this is school example and I have to follow it -.-

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it in either of these two ways :

1. Make the list `Item` list

   `ArrayList<Item> basket = new ArrayList<Item>();`

**or**

2. Type cast the object before you use them

   `((Item)basket.get(0)).getPrice();`

I would prefer the first option.

Comment: @Blip that is why, I have mentioned it in `or`, if the person doesn't parameterise the List, then type casting is the way to do.